# When does keras reset an LSTM state?

Tags: keras, lstm, keras-layer

I read all sorts of texts about it, and none seem to answer this very basic question. It's always ambiguous:

In a `stateful = False` LSTM layer, does keras reset states after:

- Each sequence; or
- Each batch?

Suppose I have X_train shaped as (1000,20,1), meaning 1000 sequences of 20 steps of a single value. If I make:

```
model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=200, nb_epoch=15)
```

Will it reset states for every single sequence (resets states 1000 times)?
Or will it reset states for every batch (resets states 5 times)?

Comment: There's a very good reading on this point: [http://philipperemy.github.io/keras-stateful-lstm/](http://philipperemy.github.io/keras-stateful-lstm/) From what I've gathered, the states are reset for every sequence (*samples* in keras terms) in a batch, after each batch.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Cheking with some tests, I got to the following conclusion, which is according to the documentation and to Nassim's answer:

First, there isn't a single state in a layer, but one state per sample in the batch. There are `batch_size` parallel states in such a layer.

#### Stateful=False

In a `stateful=False` case, all the **states are resetted together after each batch**.

- A batch with `10 sequences` would create `10 states`, and all 10 states are resetted automatically after it's processed.
- The next batch with `10 sequences` will create `10 new states`, which will also be resetted after this batch is processed

If all those sequences have `length (timesteps) = 7`, the practical result of these two batches is:

> 20 individual sequences, each with length 7

None of the sequences are related. But of course: the weights (not the states) will be unique for the layer, and will represent what the layer has learned from all the sequences.

- A state is: Where am I now inside a sequence? Which time step is it? How is this particular sequence behaving since its beginning up to now?
- A weight is: What do I know about the general behavior of all sequences I've seen so far?

#### Stateful=True

In this case, there is also the same number of parallel states, but they will **simply not be resetted at all**.

- A batch with `10 sequences` will create `10 states` that will remain as they are at the end of the batch.
- The next batch with `10 sequences` (it's required to be 10, since the first was 10) will **reuse** the same `10 states` that were created before.

The practical result is: the 10 sequences in the second batch are just continuing the 10 sequences of the first batch, as if there had been no interruption at all.

If each sequence has `length (timesteps) = 7`, then the actual meaning is:

> 10 individual sequences, each with length 14

When you see that you reached the total length of the sequences, then you call `model.reset_states()`, meaning you will not continue the previous sequences anymore, now you will start feeding new sequences.

Comment: I don't really understand when you say : "the 10 sequences in the second batch are just continuing the 10 sequences of the first batch, as if there had been no interruption at all". Could you please provide a simple example. Also, I don't understand why you write "10 individual sequences, each with length 14". Would that mean that the sequences of the second batch are temporally linked with the ones of the first batch ? Thanks

Comment: Actually, I don't understand how the sequences in the second batch are linked with the ones of the first batch through the state's conservation. If you have any (simple) maths about it, would appreciate

Comment: States are just a matrix with numbers that represent the memory of the layer. If the numbers are there, there is memory. If the numbers are reset, there isn't memory. This is the only thing that links one sequence step to another (it doesn't really matter if they're in the same batch).

Comment: @DanielMöller in your answer you mentioned " there isn't a single state in a layer, but one state per sample in the batch" I was wondering how did you test this? Is there a way to see the changes for each state in Keras?

Comment: I tested by using real sequences, cutting them in half and organizing the batches properly. Then I checked the results and they were ok. Later, I studied the source code and confirmed it again. And it's possible to check the states by using `return_state=True` in the layer. (Needs a functional API model) -- Code for `LSTMCell`, in the `call` methods. The states are `c` and the outputs are `o`. (https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/recurrent.py#L1847)

Comment: First, thankyou for your contribution to keras related answers. You said that `In a stateful=False case, all the states are resetted together after each batch.` which also looks true, but francois chollet in his first book (section 6.2) writes `The state of the RNN is reset between processing two different, independent sequences`. Does it contraction the conclusion we made that state is reset after batch? or may be he is referring to online learning with batch_size=1?

Comment: @A.B, in `stateful=False`, batch 1 and batch 2 contain completely independent sequences. There is no contradiction. (Resetting states after each batch = Resetting states between groups of independent sequences); While in `stateful = True`, batch 2 has the sequels of batch 1 (no state reset until you manually reset)

Comment: each layer has ONE state at a time. How is it possible (and what is the point) to maintain "parallel states" in each batch?

Comment: @Joseph_Marzbani, the "size" of the state matrix contains the "batch size". Which means there are "batch size" states, one for each input sequence. Except for very specific custom applications, Keras does not mix samples in a batch. Mathematically there is a single matrix, but each row of the matrix relates to one sample of the batch. Very few operations mix these samples.

Comment: If `stateful=True`, are the states reset at least at the end of each epoch?

Comment: @Dr_Zaszuś, never. You can use a `LambdaCallback` just to reset the states in case you want to use `fit` regularly.

Answer (score 14):

In Keras there are two modes for maintaining states:

1. The default mode `(stateful = False)` where the state is reset after each sample. This is because, samples/sequences in a batch are always independent and each sample/sequence has a separate state which is the representation of that sequence. Another implication is that all the signal required to process a sequence in a batch is contained in that batch and state from previous batch is not required.
2. The stateful mode where the state is never reset. It is up to the user to reset state before a new epoch, but Keras itself wont reset the state. In this mode the state is propagated from sample "i" of one batch to sample"i" of the next batch. Generally it is recommended to reset state after each epoch, as the state may grow for too long and become unstable. However in my experience with small size datasets (20,000- 40,000 samples) resetting or not resetting  the state after an epoch does not make much of a difference to the end result. For bigger datasets it may make a difference.

Stateful model will be useful if you have patterns that span over 100s of time steps. Otherwise the default mode is sufficient. In my experience setting the batch size roughly equivalent to the size (time steps) of the patterns in the data also helps.

The stateful setup could be quite difficult to grasp at first. The key to understand is if there are very long sequences which need to be divided into small sub-sequences and processed, the sub-sequences are lined up across batches and not within a batch. Within a batch the sequences are always independent. However if state needs to be carried over from one sub-sequence to another, the sub-sequences should be lined up across batches i.e. Sequence `i` of batch `n+1` is a continuation of sequence `i` from batch `n` and so on. So in this case the final state of sequence `i` from batch `n` is passed over as the initial state of sequence `i` in batch `n+1`.

References

- https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/98
- https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-use-stateful-rnns

Comment: So, in case they use states in a `stateful = False` the same way they do it for the `stateful = True`, I mean, different individual states for each sample in the batch, then resetting the states after each batch is equivalent (numerically) to resetting states after each sample (since each sample state is already a separate state. The whole question is about: If I want that each sample not interfere in the state of another sample, is `stateful=False` enough or do I have to take additional measures?

Comment: I think I am wrong regarding the default mode. Nassim's answer is correct and the state is not propagated between the samples in a batch. Within a batch, the samples are assumed to be independent. So to answer your question,  yes stateful =False is enough. I will read more and update my answer soon.

Answer (score 10):

In the [doc of the RNN code](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/recurrent.py#L152) you can read this :

> Note on using statefulness in RNNs :
>
> You can set RNN layers to be 'stateful', which means that the states
>       computed for the samples in one batch will be reused as initial states
>       for the samples in the next batch. This assumes a one-to-one mapping
>       between samples in different successive batches.

I know that this doesn't answer directly your question, but to me it confirms what I was thinking : when a LSTM is not stateful, the state is reset after every sample. They don't work by batches, the idea in a batch is that every sample is independant from each other.

So you have 1000 reset of the state for your example.

Answer (score 1):

Everyone seems to be making it too confusing. Keras LSTM resets state after every batch.

Here is a good blog: https://machinelearningmastery.com/understanding-stateful-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-python-keras/

Read `LSTM State Within A Batch` and `Stateful LSTM for a One-Char to One-Char Mapping` topics in this blog. It shows why it must reset it after batch only.

Comment: This is true if `stateful=False` but false if `stateful=True`.

Answer (score -1):

Expanding on @Nassim_Ben's answer, it is true that each sequence is considered independent for each instance of the batch. However, you need to keep in mind that the RNNs hidden state and cell memory get's passed along to the next cell for 20 steps. The hidden state and cell memory is typically set to zero for the very first cell in the 20 cells.

After the 20th cell, and after the hidden state (only, not cell memory) gets passed onto the layers above the RNN, the state gets reset. I'm going to assume that they mean cell memory and hidden state here.

So yes, it does get reset for all 1000 instances, however, considering that your `batch_size=200`, it gets reset 5 times, with each batch getting reset after they are done passing information through those 20 steps. Hopefully you got your head around this.

[Here's](https://github.com/sachinruk/deepschool.io/blob/master/Lesson%2016%20-%20LSTM%20Trump%20Tweets%20-%20Solutions.ipynb) a project I did where I had the same question. Pay special attention to cell 15 and it's explanation in the blob *after* cell 11. I kept appending letters because the state was getting reset otherwise.