# In a "many-to-one" Keras stateful LSTM network, how should I label my batches when breaking up very long sequences of data?

Tags: python, keras, lstm

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46330073/correct-way-to-split-data-to-batches-for-keras-stateful-rnns), I understand that very long sequences can be split up into batches so that the subsequences are processed separately. However, I have only one label that I am trying to predict for each sequence. Is it possible to break up a long sequence into batches if there is only one label for the entire sequence?

Comment: Following this question