# Use keras(TensorFlow) to build a Conv2D+LSTM model

Tags: python, keras, lstm

The data are 10 videos and each videos split into 86 frames and each frame has 28*28 pixels,

```
video_num = 10
frame_num = 86
pixel_num = 28*28
```

I want to use Conv2D+LSDM to build the Model, and at each time_steps(=frame_num=86) send the pixels data (=INPUT_SIZE=28*28) in the model.So the following is my code about the Model

```
BATCH_SIZE = 2 (just try)
TIME_STEPS=frame_num (=86)
INPUT_SIZE=pixel_num (=28*28)

model = Sequential()
model.add(InputLayer(batch_input_shape=(BATCH_SIZE, TIME_STEPS,     
INPUT_SIZE)))
print (model.output_shape)

model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(64,(1,3),strides=(1,1), padding='same', 
data_format='channels_last')))  ##always the error here
print (model.output_shape)

model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2),padding='same')))
print (model.output_shape)

model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(64,(1,3),strides=(1,1), 
data_format='channels_last', padding='same')))
print (model.output_shape)

model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2),padding='same')))
print (model.output_shape)

model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))
print (model.output_shape)

model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(4096, activation='relu')))
print (model.output_shape)

model.add(LSTM(100, stateful=True, return_sequences=True))
print (model.output_shape)

model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
print (model.output_shape)
```

the following figure shows the error from command line

https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4VBx.jpg
says "list index out of range"

I think that error is about the input shape in TimeDistributed() which gets the input from upper layer(InputLayer()), but I have no idea how to fix the error.
I have tried to remove the InputLayer(), and use

```
TimeDistributed(Conv2D(...), input_shape=(TIME_STEPS, INPUT_SIZE))
```

as the first layer, but also get the same error...

If anyone know about this error, please share your idea, I will be very appreciate. Also, I still didn't very clear about the difference between batch_input_shape and input_shape, did anyone use these two before?
Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A `Conv2D` layer requires four dimensions, not three:

- `(batch_size, height, width, channels)`.

And the `TimeDistributed` will require an additional dimension:

- `(batch_size, frames, height, width, channels)`

So, if you're really going to work with `TimeDistributed`+`Conv2D`, you need 5 dimensions. Your `input_shape=(86,28,28,3)`, or your `batch_input_shape=(batch_size,86,28,28,3)`, where I assumed you've got an RGB video (3 color channels).

Usually, you just pass an input shape to the `TimeDistributed`.

```
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(....), input_shape=(86,28,28,3))
```

You will need the `batch_input_shape` only in the case of using `stateful=True` LSTM's. Then you just replace the input_shape with the batch_input_shape.

---

Notice that only the convolutional 2D layers will see images in terms of height and width. When you add the LSTM's, you will need to reshape the data to bring height, width and channels into a single dimension.

For a shape (frames, h, w, ch):

```
model.add(Reshape((frames,h*w*ch)))
```

And you should not use `TimeDistributed` with these LSTMs, only with the convolutional layers.

Your approach of using `model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))` is ok instead of the reshape.

---

Notice also that Keras has recently implemented a `ConvLSTM2D` layer, which might be useful in your case: https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/#convlstm2d

Comment: Here I got another problem, how to make my input data in 5D form which also makes the last dimension "channel"

Comment: frame_all_train[video_count][frame_count][pixel_height_count]
    [pixel_width_count] = frame[pixel_height_count,pixel_width_count]               
I can only form a 4D form with my data, I am not sure that how to add one more dimension because I don't know what value I should put into the 5th dimension...

Comment: If you have a black and white video, for instance, then you have only one channel. In a numpy array, you can simply reshape it. Suppose you have an array `x_train` with shape `(10,86,28,28)`. Then: `x_train=x_train.reshape((10,86,28,28,1))`.

Comment: Oh! I see, Let me try and see if this works for me!!

Comment: It works for me again!! Thank you soooo much!!!       Do you know what dose  "Stateful" mean? I saw someone on other posts discuss about that, and in my thought, I think "Stateful" means that the hidden state in LSTM can be updated one time in each batch and initialized after one batch, but I am not very sure would it be possible that I can make the hidden state deliver from the end of previous batch to the beginning of next batch (I don't want to initialize the hidden state anymore after starting training)? If it is impossible in using the LSTM, is there any other methods can make it possible

Comment: See here :) - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43882796/when-does-keras-reset-an-lstm-state

Comment: Do you guys have an example code? I am trying to use pretrained resnet before the LSTM, but getting dimension shape error. inputs = Input(shape=(frames, img_size, img_size,channels))
x = TimeDistributed(cnn_model)(inputs)
x = Reshape((frames,150528))(x).   (h*w*ch = 150528)
x = TimeDistributed(Flatten())(x)
x = LSTM(256)(x). When training, I receive the following error: ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_5 to have 5 dimensions, but got array with shape (64, 224, 224, 3)