# Can you make an LSTM forget context manually?

Tags: machine-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am very new to machine learning and was wandering if it’s possible to manually empty an LSTM’s short term memory. Say, for instance, I wanted to train an LSTM on the sentence 
“Jack and Jill went up the,” but decided not to end the sentence. If I then wanted to train it on “Humpty dumpty sat on a wall,” how would I prevent it from immediately predicting the word “hill”? I’m using Keras.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relevant: [When does keras reset an LSTM state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43882796/when-does-keras-reset-an-lstm-state)

You should not need to reset context if your LSTM is stateless (`stateful = False`, which would make more sense for you I think) or if you train the LSTM on those two sentences by putting both in the same batch.

If you really do, use `model.reset_state()`.