# Does model.reset_states for LSTM affect any other non-LSTM layers in the model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, tf.keras

I am using the Stateful mode of LSTMs in `tf.keras` where I need to manually do `reset_states` when I have processed my sequence data, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46331227/3711266). It seems that normally people do `model.reset_states()`, but in my case my LSTM layer is embedded in a much more complex network that includes all kinds of other layers like Dense, Conv, and so forth. My question is, if I just call `model.reset_states()` on my main model that has an LSTM embedded in it (and only one LSTM), should I be worried about that reset affecting other layers in the model such as the Dense or Conv layers? Would it be better to hunt down the LSTM layer and isolate the `reset_states` call to just that layer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TLDR**: Layers like `LSTM`/`GRU` have weights and states, where layers like `Conv`/`Dense`/`Embedding` have only weights. `reset_state()` only affects layers with states.

What `reset_states()` does is that for an LSTM it resets the `c_t` and `h_t` outputs in the layer. These are the values you normally obtain by setting `LSTM(n, return_state=True)`.

`Embedding`, `Dense`, `Conv` layers don't have such states in them. So `model.reset_states()` will not affect those kind of feed forward layers. Just the sequential layers like LSTMs and GRUs.

If you like you can have a look at the [source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/1cf0898dd4331baf93fe77205550f2c2e6c90ee5/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/network.py#L446-L449) and verify that this function looks if each layer has a `reset_state` attribute in it (which feed forward layers don't have).

Answer (score 2):

Any layer with a *settable* `stateful` attribute is subject to `reset_states()`; the method iterates over each layer, checks whether it has `stateful=True` - if so, calls its `reset_states()` method; see [source](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/1cf0898dd4331baf93fe77205550f2c2e6c90ee5/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/network.py#L446-L449).

In Keras, all recurrent layers, including [ConvLSTM2D](https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/#convlstm2d), have a settable `stateful` attribute - I'm not aware of any other. `tensorflow.keras`, however, has plenty of custom layer implementations that may; you can use code below to check for sure:

```py
def print_statefuls(model):
    for layer in model.layers:
        if hasattr(layer, 'reset_states') and getattr(layer, 'stateful', False):
            print(layer.name, "is stateful")
```